# Updating physics for animated models

Tags: collision-detection, physics, performance, skeletal-animation

For a new game we have do set up a scene with a minimum of 30 bone animated models.(shooter)
The problem is that the update process for the animated models takes too long.

Thats what I do:
Each character has ~30 bones and for every update tick the animation gets calculated and every bone fires a event with the new matrix. The physics receives the event with the new matrix and updates the collision shape for that bone. The time that it takes to build the animation isn't that bad (0.2ms for 30 Bones -> 6ms for 30 models). But the main problem is that the physic engine (Bullet) uses a diffrent matrix for transformation and so its necessary to convert it.

Code for matrix conversion: (~0.005ms)

```
btTransform CLEAR_PHYSICS_API Mat_to_btTransform( Mat mat )
{
btMatrix3x3 bulletRotation;
btVector3 bulletPosition;

XMFLOAT4X4 matData = mat.GetStorage();


// copy rotation matrix
for ( int row=0; row<3; ++row )
    for ( int column=0; column<3; ++column )
        bulletRotation[row][column] = matData.m[column][row];   
for ( int column=0; column<3; ++column )
    bulletPosition[column] = matData.m[3][column];

return btTransform( bulletRotation, bulletPosition );
}
```

The function for updating the transform(Physic):

```
void CLEAR_PHYSICS_API BulletPhysics::VKinematicMove(Mat mat, ActorId aid)
{
if ( btRigidBody * const body = FindActorBody( aid ) )
{
    btTransform tmp = Mat_to_btTransform( mat );
    body->setWorldTransform( tmp ); 
    }
}
```

The real problem is the function FindActorBody(id):

```
    ActorIDToBulletActorMap::const_iterator found = m_actorBodies.find( id );
if ( found != m_actorBodies.end() )
    return found->second;
```

All physic actors are stored in m_actorBodies and thats why the updating process takes to long. But I have no idea how I could avoid this.

---

Friendly greedings,
Mathias

Comment: What is the code behind mat.GetStorage()? Calling that method over and over is unnecessary; you should store its result in a variable.

Comment: There is something wrong in your matrix transpose code. 16 ms for 100 matrices takes way too long. This is the time 60 fps games use for the entire frame, having tons of matrix operations. Please show us more code

Comment: My 1 year old mac book pro needs 1.8 ms transposing 100,000 matrices

Comment: @Ricket mat.GetStorage() return XMFLOAT4X4.

Comment: @Maik Semder The time I mentioned was for transposing, building the btTransform(bulletRotation,bulletPosition) and `body->setWorldTransform( trans );`. The transposing/building takes 0.005ms and the setWorldTransform() takes 0.0013ms (for 1 matrix).

Comment: @MathiasHölzl I understood you have 90 bodies (30 bones x 30 models), for the sake of simplicity lets say a 100 bodies. 0.005ms * 100 + 0.0013ms * 100 = 0.5ms + 0.16ms = 0.66ms nowhere near 16ms. Are you sure you got the numbers and units right? Maybe you can update your questions with the proper numbers. Then we can focus on the bottleneck.

Comment: @MathiasHölzl Well yes, it's fine that it returns something of type XMFLOAT4X4, but that wasn't my question to you. If the `GetStorage` method is, for example, doing a lookup of that matrix in a hashtable, then you're unnecessarily doing 16 hashtable lookups when you should just do one (call `mat.GetStorage()` once) and then operate on the returned matrix object. And then if this is indeed the bottleneck, you'd cut the time to around 1/16th (perhaps even less, with compiler optimizations that this might open up) which would probably be much closer to acceptable.

Comment: After your latest edit its pretty clear, dont store the bodies using the ActorId, but store them directly as btRigidBody pointer, then there is no need to translate ActorId to real pointer